# Soft Keyboard Hides Toolbar

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-toolbar

I have used Toolbar in my layout. Whenever I open the activity, and focus on the edit-text, it hides the toolbar. Please see below pictures

[image: Before Soft Keyboard opens up]

[image: After Soft Keyboard opens up]

Below is my layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.sampleactivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:background="@color/color_theme"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="App"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/past_locations"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/tags"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:maxLines="3"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` didn't help either.

How can I avoid hiding my toolbar when keyboard opens up.

Comment: Easy and simple solution: https://queception.com/question.php?question=110

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in AndroidManifest.xml solved my issue, like:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/activity_main"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
 </activity>
```

Comment: in this case the input text is hidden below keyboard

Answer (score 2):

i suggest you create a different layout for toolbar and include it in your activity

Create `toolbar.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:background="@color/color_theme"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="App"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/past_locations"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Your activity(assuming `activity_main.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.sampleactivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/tags"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:maxLines="3"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

try this if it works !!!